# Switch CASE in stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql-server

getting error in switch case

```
SELECT CASE @PurchaseId
      WHEN 1 THEN INSERT into tblPurchaseInMstr(DocNo,DocType,DocDate,PurchaseDate,SalesNodeId,SalesNodeType,FYID,LoginIDIns, TimestampIns,StatusId,InvTotPurchValue,InvTotPurchWDisc,InvNetAmt,DocSourceNodeId,DocSourceNodeType,InvTotalCGSTAmt,InvTotalSGSTAmt,InvTotalIGSTAmt)
 values(@DocNo,@DocType,@DocDate,@PurchaseDate,@SalesNodeId,@SalesNodeType,@FYID,@LoginID, GETDATE(),@StatusId,@InvTotPurchValue,@InvTotPurchWDisc,@InvNetAmt,@DocSourceNodeId,@DocSourceNodeType,@InvTotalCGSTAmt,@InvTotalSGSTAmt,@InvTotalIGSTAmt)

WHEN @PurchaseId 2 THEN UPDATE tblPurchaseInMstr set DocNo=@DocNo DocType=@DocType,DocDate=@DocDate,PurchaseDate=@PurchaseDate,SalesNodeId=@SalesNodeId,SalesNodeType=@SalesNodeType,FYID=@FYID,LoginIDUpd=@LoginId,TimestampUpd=GETDATE(),StatusId=@StatusId,InvTotPurchValue=@InvTotPurchValue,InvTotPurchWDisc=@InvTotPurchWDisc,InvNetAmt=@InvNetAmt,DocSourceNodeId=@DocSourceNodeId,DocSourceNodeType=@DocSourceNodeType,InvTotalCGSTAmt=@InvTotalCGSTAmt,InvTotalSGSTAmt=@InvTotalSGSTAmt,InvTotalIGSTAmt=@InvTotalIGSTAmt where PurchaseId=@PurchaseId

 WHEN 3 THEN DELETE tblPurchaseInMstr

 END AS Purchaseid  from tblPurchaseInMstr

END

GO
```

Comment: My crystal ball is in service at the moment. Pleases be so kind to provide the error message. Also please describe what you are trying to do. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: SWITCH CASE IS NOT IMPLEMENTING

Comment: @lipiPassi DON'T YELL AT ME!!! Please include error message in your question.

Comment: I answered your question a little while ago. In the answer, I provided an updated version of your script (with some minor bugfixes). After taking a second look at it, I saw something alarming I didn't notice before. It seems that your variable `@PurchaseID` is used for both the ID field of your table (primary key?) and for controlling the execution logic (with values 1, 2 or 3). I suppose the execution logic variable should be a different variable in your final script?

Comment: @HoneyBadger its nothing like that

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute queries in a CASE expression. A case expression is... well... just an expression that should produce a value.

If you want to execute statements based on a variable/parameter value, use IF blocks

And I assume you don't want to delete the entire table in case of value 3... ;)

**Edit:**

I just added a comment with a question in your original post (regarding `@PurchaseId` acting as both the execution logic variable and the record ID/key variable).

I updated the first IF-block to fetch the inserted ID value into `@PurchaseId`, assuming `tblPurchaseInMstr.PurchaseId` is an identity column.

And I introduced a variable/parameter `@Action` that represents the action to take: 1 = insert, 2 = update, 3 = delete.

```
IF @Action = 1 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblPurchaseInMstr
    (
        DocNo,DocType,DocDate,PurchaseDate,SalesNodeId,SalesNodeType,FYID,LoginIDIns,
        TimestampIns,StatusId,InvTotPurchValue,InvTotPurchWDisc,InvNetAmt,DocSourceNodeId,
        DocSourceNodeType,InvTotalCGSTAmt,InvTotalSGSTAmt,InvTotalIGSTAmt
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @DocNo,@DocType,@DocDate,@PurchaseDate,@SalesNodeId,@SalesNodeType,@FYID,@LoginID,
        GETDATE(),@StatusId,@InvTotPurchValue,@InvTotPurchWDisc,@InvNetAmt,@DocSourceNodeId,
        @DocSourceNodeType,@InvTotalCGSTAmt,@InvTotalSGSTAmt,@InvTotalIGSTAmt
    );

    SET @PurchaseId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;

IF @Action = 2 BEGIN
    UPDATE tblPurchaseInMstr
    SET
        DocNo=@DocNo, DocType=@DocType,DocDate=@DocDate,PurchaseDate=@PurchaseDate,SalesNodeId=@SalesNodeId,SalesNodeType=@SalesNodeType,FYID=@FYID,LoginIDUpd=@LoginId,
        TimestampUpd=GETDATE(),StatusId=@StatusId,InvTotPurchValue=@InvTotPurchValue,InvTotPurchWDisc=@InvTotPurchWDisc,InvNetAmt=@InvNetAmt,DocSourceNodeId=@DocSourceNodeId,
        DocSourceNodeType=@DocSourceNodeType,InvTotalCGSTAmt=@InvTotalCGSTAmt,InvTotalSGSTAmt=@InvTotalSGSTAmt,InvTotalIGSTAmt=@InvTotalIGSTAmt
    WHERE PurchaseId = @PurchaseId;
END;

IF @Action = 3 BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tblPurchaseInMstr
    WHERE PurchaseId = @PurchaseId;
END;

SELECT @PurchaseId AS PurchaseId;
```

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` in sql server is a function. It returns data based on other data. It does not accept statements, it does not control program flow.

There is no `switch` in sql-server. You can only use `IF`:

```
If @PurchaseId=1 insert into tblPurchaseInMstr(...
If @PurchaseId=2 UPDATE tblPurchaseInMstr...
```

and so on.